# On an Integral inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, inequality

I am following a proof and I am having troubles with the last inequality stated

[image]

Specifically could I have some extra passages on this? $$\int_{\delta}^{\pi} [f(w+u) - f(w)] \frac{\sin^2(nu/2)}{2 \sin^2(u/2)}du \le \frac{1}{2\sin^2(\frac{\delta}{2})}\int_{0}^{\pi} [f(w+u) - f(w)] du $$

Answer (score 3):

This uses the fact that 
$$ \frac{\sin^2(nu/2)}{2 \sin^2(u/2)}\leqslant \frac{1}{2\sin^2(\delta)/2}, $$
which follows from the elementary inequality $\sin^2(nu/2)\leqslant 1$ and increasingness of the map $u\mapsto \sin^2(u/2)$ on the interval $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: Thanks! I understood this inequality, but even if it holds on the interval $[0, \pi]$ why can we expand the limits of the integral to $\int_0^\pi$? should they not be kept as $\int_\delta^\pi$?

Comment: We can, since we have absolute values.

Answer (score 1):

This holds because of

$ | \sin^2(nu/2) | \leq 1$

and

$ |\sin^2(u/2)| \geq | \sin^2(\delta/2)$ if $\delta \in [0,\pi]$

Comment: Shouldn't this inequality hold always?

Comment: @Monolite thx, i made an edit to make it more accurate

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\left|\frac{1}{n\pi}\int_{\delta}^{\pi}[f(\omega+u)-f(\omega)]\frac{\sin^2(nu/2)}{2\sin^2(u/2)}du\right|\le \frac{1}{n\pi}\int_{\delta}^{\pi}\left|f(\omega -u)-f(\omega)\right|\frac{\sin^2(nu/2)}{2\sin^2(u/2)}du$$

Next, we note that in the interval $[0,\pi]$, $2\sin(u/2)\ge 2\sin(\delta/2)$ and therefore $\frac{1}{2\sin(u/2)}\le \frac{1}{2\sin(\delta/2)}$.

We also have the inequality $\sin^2(nu/2)\le 1$.

Putting it all together gives the stated inequality.